# How to display asterisk mark only if the value of sales status is 2

Tags: laravel

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-all-closer col-all-closer--leftend @if($errors->has('product_code')) has-error @endif" id="product_code_form">
        <div class="form-group @if(old('sales_status') !== '01') required @endif">
          <label for="PageTemplateDomain"><span class="label-text">商品コード</span></label>
          <input name="product_code" class="form-control" maxlength="100" value="{{ old('product_code') }}" type="text" id="product_code" @if(old('sales_status') !== '01') required="required" @endif>
          <div id="product_code_error_msg">
          @foreach($errors->get('product_code') as $message)
            <p class="help-block" id="geterrormsg">{{ $message }}</p>
          @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where in your code do you want to do that? What have you already tried? What's the expected vs the actual output?

Comment: It looks like your templating language already has a test against `sales_status` - try using that approach? Is this Blade?

Comment: i want to make a product form in which i want to display asterisk mark only if the value of sales_status is  02 that means when i click the radio button of sales status having value 02 ,it should display the asterisk mark on product code column . but when i clicked sales_status radio button value 01 or 03 it should not display asterisk mark on the same column i.e product_code .

Comment: yes its a laravel blade .

Comment: Where is this radio button? Sounds like you need javascript for that

Comment: may be i have made my question too complicated. actually i want to ask that how i can hide/show  asterisk mark using radio button . i